# Conditional Statements in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**I have two types of users in my app. I wish to detect their presence online via firebase firestore and realtime data base. However, only the user1 condition statement executes when I deploy it.**

//  here is the cloud function

```
 exports.onUserStatusChange = functions.database
  .ref("/{uid}/presence")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    // Get the data written to Realtime Database
    const isOnline = change.after.val();

    // Get a User1 reference to the Firestore document
    const user1StatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`user1_data/${context.params.uid}`);
    // Get a  User2 reference to the Firestore document
    const user2StatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`user2_data/${context.params.uid}`);

    console.log(`status: ${isOnline}`);


    //   // Update the values on Firestore

    if (user1StatusFirestoreRef) {
      return user1StatusFirestoreRef.update(
        {
          presence: isOnline,
          last_seen: Date.now(),
        }


      );

    }

    if (user2StatusFirestoreRef) {
      return user2StatusFirestoreRef.update(
        {
          presence: isOnline,
          last_seen: Date.now(),
        }


      );

    }








  });
```

Comment: Can a given user satisfy both conditions?. If so would you want to update both locations in firestore?

Comment: a given user cannot satisfy both conditions. There are two  categories of users in the app. I want a situation where if either of the user categories opens the app, the appropriate  condition fires the required function.  For now only the first condition works.

Comment: In that case you should get contents of the references first. The reference variable for condition user1 will always have a value even if the underlying location in database doesn't have a value. Please read through the firebase docs to understand difference between creating a reference variable and fetching underlying data. Check this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists

Comment: Thanks. This method worked for me:  return promise.all([ condition1, condition2]);

Comment: Will frame a proper answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check two conditions and then update the database, first you need to get contents of the references.
The reference variable for condition user1 will always have a value even if the underlying location in database doesn't have a value. Instead you need to check if the underlying value exists.

This will have to be done though asynchronous coding (promise) since you need to check not one but two locations.

Please read through the firebase docs to understand difference between creating a reference variable and fetching underlying data. Check this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists

Answer (score 0):

```
 exports.onUserStatusChange = functions.database
  .ref("/{uid}/presence")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    // Get the data written to Realtime Database
    const isOnline = change.after.val();

    // Get a User1 reference to the Firestore document
    const user1StatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`user1_data/${context.params.uid}`);
    // Get a  User2 reference to the Firestore document
    const user2StatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`user2_data/${context.params.uid}`);

    console.log(`status: ${isOnline}`);


    //   // Update the values on Firestore

return promise.all([
 user1StatusFirestoreRef.update(
        {
          presence: isOnline,
          last_seen: Date.now(),
        }


      ),
 user2StatusFirestoreRef.update(
        {
          presence: isOnline,
          last_seen: Date.now(),
        }


      );

]);

  




  });
```